# change the value of dropdown list after form submition ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very strange problem. I want to change selected value of the dropdownlist after form submition. I know that HtmlHelper is retrieving the ModelState value, which is filled with the posted data. But I have a redirect from my POST action to GET action! However my ddl is populated with value submitted during the post. I've also added this code to my post action: ModelState.Clear(), but this hasn't helped me neither.

I've added another ddl to my form just for debugging;

```
   @Html.DropDownList("asd" + Guid.NewGuid(), Model.Voting.Result.ToSelectList())
```

It always appears with value provided by the server code. But the target ddl

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Voting.Result, Model.Voting.Result.ToSelectList())
```

always has a value posted by user.
How can I populate the target ddl?

Comment: If ModelState.Clear() is called before redirecting to your "get" view and that didn't help then you should double check your code as that just work.

Comment: I see and checked my code. But @Html.DropDownList("asd" + Guid.NewGuid(), Model.Voting.Result.ToSelectList()) works fine. So the problem might be in the method @Html.DropDownListFor

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the initial value to it like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Voting.Result, 
new SelectList(Model.Voting.Result, "Id", "Name", /*initial value*/))
```

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) constructor of [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx) class

Edit
initially I have put the argument on wrong method

Comment: The 3rd parameter is 'object htmlAttributes' or 'string optionLabel'. I've tried to pass the value as  the3rd param and this hasn't helped me.

Comment: convert it to a string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504970(v=VS.98).aspx

Comment: making this change added one more item to the result <select> element. This item is selected. So one item is duplicated in the result ddl :(

Comment: I do use this constructor with 3rd argument specified.